# Docker and Zeppelin OS priviledges

Tags: shell, docker, operating-system, apache-zeppelin

I have dockerized the Zeppelin application. Now I want to see what OS privileges does docker and zeppelin each has.

I have tries some commands as shown below, but it is not giving me expected output.

```
docker service ls 

docker service inspect --pretty redis
```

Also, what is the command to list out all the services which can possibly be available in docker?

Comment: Hi, I just read your question and have a question. If you don't mind could you describe what you want to do eventually? after checking privileges?